# No onSeekTo event in YouTube player api?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I need a callback when the user seeks to a new position in a YouTube video.
I looked at the YouTube Javascript and iframe APIs, and it seems there is no such event in the api.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: However there is a seekTo function, so I guess I have no other option but disabling the YouTube player's built-in controls and make my own controls including a seek bar...

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found a way without giving up on the YouTube embedded controls.
The idea is to monitor the current time in a timeout callback and triggering an event (of directly a callback function) whenever the time difference is "abnormal". Not the most fine-grained technique, as the check is performed twice a second, but it does the job when we need to handle seekTo events at the high level.
Hope this will help others until Google decides to invest in updating the API.

Here is a modified version of the example given on the YouTube iframe API official documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        console.log("YouTube API ready");

        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log("YouTube video ready");
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        switch(event.data) {
            case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
                console.log("YouTube video CUED");
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                console.log("YouTube video PLAYING");
                isPlaying = true;
                checkSeek();
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
                console.log("YouTube video BUFFERING");
                isPlaying = false;
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                console.log("YouTube video PAUSED");
                isPlaying = false;
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                console.log("YouTube video ENDED");
                isPlaying = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    //  A hack to work around the missing seek event 
    var checkSeekPeriod = 500;
    var checkSeekMargin = 500;
    var prevCurrentTime = 0;
    var isPlaying = false;
    function checkSeek() 
    {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            prevCurrentTime = -1;
            return;
        }

        var currentTime= player.getCurrentTime();
        if(prevCurrentTime > 0)
        {
            var diff = (currentTime - prevCurrentTime) * 1000;
            if(Math.abs(diff - checkSeekPeriod) > checkSeekMargin)
            {
                console.log("checkSeek diff = " + diff.toFixed(0) + "ms");
                onPlayerSeekTo(currentTime);
            }
        }
        prevCurrentTime = currentTime;

        setTimeout(function() {
                return checkSeek();
            }, checkSeekPeriod);
    };

    function onPlayerSeekTo(t) {
        console.log("YouTube player seek: " + t + "s");
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is not reliable. Jumping around a video it only detects the seek on occasion.